# Only Send dataLayer once on Scroll Percentage

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-tag-manager, google-datalayer

I am looking for some direction on this piece of jQuery. There is probably a better way to do this but basically I am trying to send a dataLayer variable when a user gets to 50% scroll of the page and send another when they get to 75% of the page.

```
$(window).on('scroll', function(){
  var s = $(window).scrollTop(),
  d = $(document).height(),
  c = $(window).height();

  var scrollPercent = (s / (d - c)) * 100;

  if (scrollPercent > 74 && scrollPercent < 76) {
  dataLayer.push({'Project Profile':'75% Scrolled'})
  };

  if (scrollPercent > 49 && scrollPercent < 51) {
  dataLayer.push({'Project Profile':'50% Scrolled'})
  };
})
```

Since the numbers can be 74.23413424, 74.3495490, etc. It fires a ton of times between the min of 74 and max of 76.

Is there a better way to do this? Is there a way to only send one dataLayer.push? I assume the answer to both are yes. I just have no idea how! Thanks in advance for the help.

Brian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You really only need some kind of flag that will be marked once you reach your 74%. For example:

```js
let flag1 = false;
let flag2 = false;
$(window).on('scroll', function(){
    var s = $(window).scrollTop(),
    d = $(document).height(),
    c = $(window).height();

    var scrollPercent = (s / (d - c)) * 100;

    if (scrollPercent > 74 && !flag1) {
        dataLayer.push({'Project Profile':'75% Scrolled'});
        flag1 = true;
    };

    if (scrollPercent > 49 && !flag2) {
        dataLayer.push({'Project Profile':'50% Scrolled'});
        flag2 = true;
    };
})
```

2. You don't actually need JQuery for this. GTM has now built-in Trigger that captures scroll depth. You can read more in this [post](https://www.simoahava.com/analytics/scroll-depth-trigger-google-tag-manager/)

Comment: This helped me a TON! It not only showed me how to write something like this in jQuery but also showed me a super easy way to do this in GTM....AND I found a great blog that goes other GTM tricks!

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps try detecting when it goes in that range and triggered when it leaves that range.

```
    var inRange = false;
    var inRange2 = false;
    $(window).on('scroll', function(){
      var s = $(window).scrollTop(),
      d = $(document).height(),
      c = $(window).height();

      var scrollPercent = Math.round((s / (d - c)) * 100);

      if (scrollPercent > 74 && scrollPercent < 76 && !inRange) {
      inRange = true;
      };

if (scrollPercent < 75 && scrollPercent > 75 && inRange) {
      inRange = false;
      dataLayer.push({'Project Profile':'75% Scrolled'});
      };

      if (scrollPercent > 49 && scrollPercent < 51 && !inRange2) {
      inRange2 = true;
      };

      if (scrollPercent > 50 && scrollPercent < 50 && inRange2) {
      inRange2 = false;
      dataLayer.push({'Project Profile':'50% Scrolled'});
      };
    })
```

Comment: Thanks for chiming in! This didn't end up working for me for whatever reason. But someone else answered with a method that worked. Thanks!